# Pylint considers "timeout-methods" option as unrecognised

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

Versions:

- Python: 3.10.4
- Pylint: 2.15.3
- Visual Studio Code: 1.72.2

The `.pylintrc` file was generated using

```
pylint --generate-rcfile
```

command.

It has the following option configured:

```
[METHOD_ARGS]

# List of qualified names (i.e., library.method) which require a timeout
# parameter e.g. 'requests.api.get,requests.api.post'
timeout-methods=requests.api.delete,requests.api.get,requests.api.head,requests.api.options,requests.api.patch,requests.api.post,requests.api.put,requests.api.request
```

However I see an error which sounds:

```
Unrecognized option found: timeout-methods Pylint(E0015:unrecognized-option)
```

The documentation states that option `timeout-methods` is supported: https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#timeout-methods.

So I am lost why do I have that error displayed by pylint in visual studio code.

Comment: Are you using the Pylint extension for VS Code or do you run Pylint from the command line? The VS Code extension comes with a bundled Pylint version, which may be too old (at the time of writing the extension readme says it comes with Pylint 2.14.5, which does not know about the timeout-methods option yet).

Comment: You are correct, I am using VS Code extension whereas .pylintrc file was generated running Pylint from command line. So I understand now where discrepancy comes from. Looks like I can't update the version of Pylint used by VS Code but how can I generate another .pylintrc file with that bundled to extension version?

Comment: I can simply remove that configuration from .pylintrc but wanted to be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments under the original code showed, the `pylint` version bundled in the VS Code extension and the one that was used to generate the `.pylintrc` file differ.

Normally, the VS Code Pylint extension should use the `pylint` version installed in the Python environment that you configured to use for your project, and only falls back to the bundled version if no other `pylint` version was found. See also the [extension docs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.pylint) for details.

Check the following:

1. Make sure that you configured the correct Python environment for your project. See [Select a Python interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter) in the docs.
2. Make sure that you have installed `pylint` in the Python environment you have configured for your project, and are not accidentally using a `pylint` installation from your global Python environment. After configuring the Python interpreter (see step 1), once you open a new terminal in VS Code this environment should be activated by default. Run `pip list | grep pylint` (macOS/Linux) or `pip list | findstr pylint` (Windows) to check if `pylint` is installed.
3. If both 1 & 2 are fulfilled and you still have problems, check if `pylint.importStrategy` is maybe set to `useBundled` in your VS Code `settings.json`, and remove it or set it to `fromEnvironment`.

Answer (score 1):

pylint 2.15 take this option into account correctly. But it was released only 2 month ago. Your error must come from the pylint version included in visual studio code that might lag a little behind and do not handle it yet.